# Is writing a reference atomic on 64bit VMs

Tags: java, reference, atomic, memory-model

The java memory model mandates that writing a `int` is atomic: That is, if you write a value to it (consisting of 4 bytes) in one thread and read it in another, you will get all bytes or none, but never 2 new bytes and 2 old bytes or such.

This is not guaranteed for `long`. Here, writing `0x1122334455667788` to a variable holding `0` before could result in another thread reading `0x112233440000000` or `0x0000000055667788`.

Now the specification does not mandate object references to be either int or long-sized. For type safety reasons I suspect they are guaranteed to be written atomically, but on a 64bit VM these references could be very well 64bit values (merely memory addresses).

Now here are my questions:

- Are there any memory model specs covering this (that I haven't found)?
- Are long-writes suspect to be atomic on 64bit VMs?
- Are VMs forced to map references to 32bit?

Regards,
  Steffen

Comment: @Steffen Heil: nitpicking but note that not all references are 64 bit internally even on 64 bit VM (due to the amazing amount of waste 64 bit references are generating).  Modern VMs are using pointer compression/reference compression called *"CompressedOops"*: http://wikis.sun.com/display/HotSpotInternals/CompressedOops  So I don't disagree that they *could* be 64 bit value but they often aren't (not that it changes much to the answer that Dirk posted).

Answer (score 65, accepted):

## Reading/writing references always atomic

See [JLS section 17.7: Non-atomic Treatment of double and long](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.7)

> For the purposes of the Java programming language memory model, a
>   single write to a non-volatile long or double value is treated as two
>   separate writes: one to each 32-bit half. This can result in a
>   situation where a thread sees the first 32 bits of a 64-bit value from
>   one write, and the second 32 bits from another write.
>
> Writes and reads of volatile long and double values are always atomic.
>
> **Writes to and reads of references are always atomic, regardless of
>   whether they are implemented as 32-bit or 64-bit values.**
>
> Some implementations may find it convenient to divide a single write
>   action on a 64-bit long or double value into two write actions on
>   adjacent 32-bit values. For efficiency's sake, this behavior is
>   implementation-specific; an implementation of the Java Virtual Machine
>   is free to perform writes to long and double values atomically or in
>   two parts.
>
> Implementations of the Java Virtual Machine are encouraged to avoid
>   splitting 64-bit values where possible. Programmers are encouraged to
>   declare shared 64-bit values as volatile or synchronize their programs
>   correctly to avoid possible complications.

(Emphasis added)

## `AtomicReference`

If you want to coordinate between old and new values, or want [specific memory effects](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/invoke/VarHandle.html), use the class [`AtomicReference`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicReference.html).

For example, [`AtomicReference::getAndSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicReference.html#getAndSet(V)) returns the old value while setting the new value atomically, eliminating any chance of another thread having intervened between the two steps. Uses [`volatile` memory semantics](https://stackoverflow.com/q/106591/642706).

Comment: Ok, I missed the point in the specs again. Seems to me, I am too tired and should sleep instead of asking questions... Thanks for the pointer. (AGAIN)

Comment: If "Writes to and reads of references are always atomic, regardless of whether they are implemented as 32 or 64 bit values.", why do we have class AtomicReference (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicReference.html)?
Only because of methods getAndSet/compareAndSet?

Comment: Not seeing torn reference values is only part of the picture. The `AtomicReference` exists primarily for its synchronization API (the `compareAndSet` you alluded to), @mc.android.developer, and there is no "only" here. That's actually the important part.